# Media Foundation Source Reader : Video timestamp increase additional 16 ms every N samples

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I have a real time application of webcam. I use Source Reader of Media Foundation in Win 10 to capture video in real time. Everything works fine, except the timestamp. I need to know when the sample is captured, so I record the timestamp with each sample, and check the time difference between samples. For testing, I didn't copy the video content, just record the timestamp. I use 30 Hz frame rate, and got the following result,

Sample Index ,      Timestamp  ,  difference between sample

Sample   1, 64285.17787 s, 32.07 ms

Sample   2, 64285.20989 s, 32.02 ms

Sample   3, 64285.24188 s, 32.00 ms

Sample   4, 64285.27385 s, 31.97 ms

Sample   5, 64285.30589 s, 32.04 ms

Sample   6, 64285.33794 s, 32.05 ms

Sample   7, 64285.36990 s, 31.96 ms

Sample   8, 64285.41776 s, 47.86 ms ?????

Sample   9, 64285.44984 s, 32.08 ms

Sample  10, 64285.48187 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  11, 64285.51386 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  12, 64285.54589 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  13, 64285.57786 s, 31.97 ms

Sample  14, 64285.60992 s, 32.06 ms

Sample  15, 64285.64186 s, 31.94 ms

Sample  16, 64285.67385 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  17, 64285.70588 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  18, 64285.73792 s, 32.04 ms

Sample  19, 64285.76988 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  20, 64285.80191 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  21, 64285.83392 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  22, 64285.86587 s, 31.95 ms

Sample  23, 64285.91385 s, 47.98 ms ?????

Sample  24, 64285.94586 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  25, 64285.97788 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  26, 64286.00986 s, 31.98 ms

Sample  27, 64286.04182 s, 31.95 ms

Sample  28, 64286.07388 s, 32.06 ms

Sample  29, 64286.10588 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  30, 64286.13785 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  31, 64286.16990 s, 32.06 ms

Sample  32, 64286.20190 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  33, 64286.23391 s, 32.01 ms

Sample  34, 64286.26586 s, 31.95 ms

Sample  35, 64286.29786 s, 32.01 ms

Sample  36, 64286.32986 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  37, 64286.37787 s, 48.00 ms ?????

Sample  38, 64286.40984 s, 31.98 ms

Sample  39, 64286.44184 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  40, 64286.47388 s, 32.05 ms

Sample  41, 64286.50588 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  42, 64286.53785 s, 31.98 ms

Sample  43, 64286.56987 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  44, 64286.60190 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  45, 64286.63385 s, 31.94 ms

Sample  46, 64286.66597 s, 32.12 ms

Sample  47, 64286.69790 s, 31.93 ms

Sample  48, 64286.72986 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  49, 64286.76186 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  50, 64286.79386 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  51, 64286.84188 s, 48.02 ms ?????

Sample  52, 64286.87388 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  53, 64286.90585 s, 31.97 ms

Sample  54, 64286.93785 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  55, 64286.96988 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  56, 64287.00184 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  57, 64287.03385 s, 32.01 ms

Sample  58, 64287.06594 s, 32.09 ms

Sample  59, 64287.09789 s, 31.95 ms

Sample  60, 64287.12985 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  61, 64287.16189 s, 32.04 ms

Sample  62, 64287.19389 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  63, 64287.22586 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  64, 64287.25788 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  65, 64287.30587 s, 47.99 ms ?????

Sample  66, 64287.33787 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  67, 64287.36985 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  68, 64287.40184 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  69, 64287.43387 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  70, 64287.46589 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  71, 64287.49785 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  72, 64287.52986 s, 32.01 ms

Sample  73, 64287.56188 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  74, 64287.59385 s, 31.97 ms

Sample  75, 64287.62587 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  76, 64287.65793 s, 32.06 ms

Sample  77, 64287.68991 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  78, 64287.72186 s, 31.95 ms

Sample  79, 64287.76982 s, 47.96 ms ?????

Sample  80, 64287.80187 s, 32.05 ms

Sample  81, 64287.83388 s, 32.01 ms

Sample  82, 64287.86584 s, 31.96 ms

Sample  83, 64287.89783 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  84, 64287.92985 s, 32.01 ms

Sample  85, 64287.96186 s, 32.01 ms

Sample  86, 64287.99384 s, 31.98 ms

Sample  87, 64288.02587 s, 32.03 ms

Sample  88, 64288.05787 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  89, 64288.08989 s, 32.02 ms

Sample  90, 64288.12190 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  91, 64288.15388 s, 31.98 ms

Sample  92, 64288.18587 s, 31.99 ms

Sample  93, 64288.23383 s, 47.96 ms ?????

Sample  94, 64288.26583 s, 32.00 ms

Sample  95, 64288.29787 s, 32.04 ms

Sample  96, 64288.32992 s, 32.05 ms

Sample  97, 64288.36182 s, 31.90 ms

Sample  98, 64288.39386 s, 32.04 ms

Sample  99, 64288.42588 s, 32.02 ms

Sample 100, 64288.45784 s, 31.96 ms

Sample 101, 64288.48988 s, 32.04 ms

Sample 102, 64288.52189 s, 32.01 ms

Sample 103, 64288.55388 s, 31.99 ms

Sample 104, 64288.58586 s, 31.97 ms

Sample 105, 64288.61785 s, 32.00 ms

Sample 106, 64288.64998 s, 32.13 ms

Sample 107, 64288.69791 s, 47.93 ms ?????

Sample 108, 64288.72983 s, 31.93 ms

Sample 109, 64288.76188 s, 32.05 ms

Sample 110, 64288.79388 s, 31.99 ms

Sample 111, 64288.82585 s, 31.97 ms

Sample 112, 64288.85785 s, 32.00 ms

Sample 113, 64288.88987 s, 32.02 ms

Sample 114, 64288.92188 s, 32.01 ms

Sample 115, 64288.95390 s, 32.02 ms

Sample 116, 64288.98587 s, 31.97 ms

Sample 117, 64289.01790 s, 32.02 ms

Sample 118, 64289.04986 s, 31.96 ms

Sample 119, 64289.08186 s, 32.00 ms

Sample 120, 64289.11386 s, 32.01 ms

Sample 121, 64289.16185 s, 47.98 ms ?????

Sample 122, 64289.19386 s, 32.01 ms

Sample 123, 64289.22584 s, 31.98 ms

Sample 124, 64289.25785 s, 32.01 ms

Sample 125, 64289.28987 s, 32.02 ms

Sample 126, 64289.32184 s, 31.96 ms

Sample 127, 64289.35385 s, 32.01 ms

Sample 128, 64289.38589 s, 32.04 ms

Sample 129, 64289.41786 s, 31.98 ms

Sample 130, 64289.44982 s, 31.96 ms

Sample 131, 64289.48188 s, 32.06 ms

Sample 132, 64289.51388 s, 32.00 ms

Sample 133, 64289.54585 s, 31.97 ms

Sample 134, 64289.57786 s, 32.01 ms

Sample 135, 64289.62588 s, 48.02 ms ?????

The interval between samples will increase additional 16 ms every 14 samples. The average period is 33 ms, which is consistent with 30 Hz. But I need a stable period 33 ms, not average 33 ms.

I have tried different frame rate and different webcam. The scenario is the same. It will increase additional 16 ms every N samples. (N may be different for different frame rate and different webcam). I also use QueryPerformanceCounter to verify. It shows the same result.

I don't think the webcam will delay periodically. I guess the Source Reader has some internal buffer and do some post processing. I try to use MFMediaSource and MFMediaStream directly, but it doesn't output any sample. I must back to Source Reader.

My capture code is the same as the sample in SDK. (MFCaptureD3D)

Does anyone know how to make Source Reader to produce a stable sample period ?

Thanks in advance.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Most web cameras, and especially consumer grade ones and those built in laptops, do not have to generate requested or promised number of frames. Overall the configuration frame rate should be interpreted as "maximal number of frames per second" the camera is to provide. If you are interested in having as many frames as possible, you just start the camera with the setting that promises the highest fps. If you are interested to get capped rate you then respectively update the setup.

Many cameras respond to low light conditions by reducing effective frame rate. This does not have to be smooth, so the camera just skips some of the frames with behavior that you are seeing.

The easiest thing to try is to point the camera to something bright and then check if it captures at smooth high frame rate. If this is the case and in other situation the camera does some skipping, then it's just the way the camera and the driver repsond to low light conditions.

Comment: I understand that low light condition may reduce frame rate. But in the case, the webcam output samples in a rate greater than 30 Hz for several samples and then drop one sample.

Comment: The average rate is close to 30 Hz. This is a strange behavior. I don't know it is a webcam problem or a Media Foundation problem.